# How can two same reactions have a different reduction potential

Tags: electrochemistry

According to wikipedia the reduction of AgCl (s) to give Ag (s) and $Cl^-$ (aq) has reduction potential of 0.22 V . But it also says tha the reduction of $Ag^+$ (aq) to give Ag (s) has reduction potential of 0.80 V . In the former reaction the oxidation state of +1 and gets reduced to zero oxidation state and chloride acts as spectator ion whereas the same happens in the latter reaction just without the chloride ion. Also I believe silver chloride is a strong electrolyte and dissociates completely. So my question is If both the reactions are exactly identical then why isn't there reduction potential same ? I am super confused, any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: 1) AgBr not AgCl? Check again perhaps? 2) AgCl isn't a strong electrolyte at all 3) See [Why the reduction potential of the reaction AgCl (aq) /Ag + Cl- is +0.22V](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/61617/16683)

Comment: Sorry that was a typo it is agcl

Comment: Ok if agcl is insoluble in water then how is it electrolysed is it done in molten state?

Comment: AgCl will dissolve better in a NaCl (aq) or NH4OH solution.